# How to identify if the file is an Image (.jpg, .png ...) with Java/JavaFX?

Tags: java, image, file, javafx

I was searching for how to I can identify or check if the file selected by the user is an Image (eg of extension: .jpg or .png or .bmp and more). **Note that the image is not just one file it's list of images.**
I've tried this code:

```
final File folder = new File( oo );
final File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();
ImageView imageView = new ImageView();
String mimeType = new MimetypesFileTypeMap().getContentType( folder );
String type = mimeType.split( "/" )[0].toLowerCase();
if ( !type.equals( "image" ) ) {
    //TODO
}
else {
    //TODO
}
```

After trying that code nothing changed i still get the problem. How i can do so and thanks a lot :-)

Answer (score 0):

What do you expect to get from getContentType if you pass in the folder instead of a file from the listOfFiles?

Answer (score 0):

You have to loop over all files of the array "listOfFiles" and check the mime of each entry. I would suggest that you add a boolean flag which you start with **true**. If you find one file that isn't an image, you set the flag to **false**.
If the flag is still **true** after the loop, you can continue. Otherwise, you show an error dialog.